# JPA. Getting data part from data base

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Let's say we have a user table and the table of note. Communication one to many .
And when I get using Spring jpa a list of all users , I do not want to just get it objects notes.

It is clear that you can manually using annotations to specify in essence, that the notes did not receive objects from the database. But I need to do it dynamically.

Q - Can I do that?

Comment: I have no idea what this means

Comment: For dynamic queries you can use Criteria API or Querydsl.